# Where can I find the full documentation for new Winter 18 lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, documentation, winter18

The [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_lc_components.htm) for Winter 18 (v41) include a number of new advanced components like `lightning:notificationsLibrary`. However, when I visit both the documentation app in my org and the standard [web documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm) these components are absent. Where can I find info on the new library components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you just missed it, but it is documented in the [Lightning components developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_notificationsLibrary.htm)

component

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
    <lightning:button name="notice" label="Show Notice" onclick="{!c.handleShowNotice}"/>
</aura:component>
```

js controller

```
({    
    handleShowNotice : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('notifLib').showNotice({
            "variant": "error",
            "header": "Something has gone wrong!",
            "message": "Unfortunately, there was a problem updating the record.",
            closeCallback: function() {
                alert('You closed the alert!');
            }
        });
    }
})
```

However, I do understand the frustration of looking for it in the docs and not finding it:
[image]

A good place to search would be the [H&T Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/home) or Google:

[image]

Usually, I check my orgs Auradocs, however, not all components are documented there when newly released unfortunately

> MyOrg.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app

In the H&T portal you can create some predefined queries (not very user friendly) however, if you have an understanding of the underlying index and the [query syntax](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/user/coveo_query_syntax_reference.htm), you can do something similar to this:

> (@sfhtdeveloperdocumentschtmlurlc~= "aura_compref" OR
>   @sfhtdeveloperdocumentschtmlurlc~= "ref_lightning")

This will basically query for every fieldname @sfsomething with a fuzzy match of "Term" in your query, you can also use AND, OR operators to narrow down search results. This is particularly useful if you want to find documents that fit a certain criteria. To check field information on the documents, you can do ALT+Double click which will provide all the field values you can filter on.